# Which class is comparable implemented if you have an object of objects?

Tags: arrays, comparable, compareto

If I have a Classroom class (which implements a generic interface) with  Classroom[] roster containing various Student objects (each of which have an int Age), which class do I implement comparable and compareTo to sort my roster by age (in ascending order)?

Comment: Does ‘roaster’ field contain array of classroom or student?

Comment: @UditBhatia roster is an array of students

Answer (score 1):

Here are few options, it will use the natural order to sort and for int natural order is ascending.

```
Comparator<Student> studentAgeComparator
  = Comparator.comparing(Student::getAge);

Arrays.sort(roaster, studentAgeComparator);
```

I hope this helps